# Compilation issue with VisualStudio Enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Has anyone encountered this before? Or am I doing something wrong?

I have a 4 C# projects A, B, C and D.

Project B has two functions overloaded with different type of parameters (one of which accepts a parameter of type that is defined in Project C and the other accepts a parameter of a type that is defined in project D). (Project B has reference to both C and D)

Project A has reference to B and C and trying to call above overload function in B with parameter of type that is defined in C.

On Visual Studio 2015, Compiler is complaining about missing reference to project D in A.

When the same project A is compiled in Visual Studio 2013, It is working fine.

It is an issue with VS2015? OR with latest c# compilers, is it mandatory that we will have to include all Dlls including the one that we are not using in current project?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055
```

Some Screens:

[image: Solution]

[image: Function OverLoads]

**Visual Studio 2015 Error:**

[image]

Comment: what compiling error?

Comment: I just edited OP with some additional data.

Comment: are all the assemblies of same .net version?

Comment: Yes they are (4.5)